# Between Operator Big Query Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

Using Standard SQL in BQ - as part of a task I want to search for records created between 2pm the previous day & 2pm on current day

I have found

`SELECT DATETIME_SUB(DATETIME_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATETIME(), DAY), INTERVAL 10 hour)`  Gives me 2PM yesterday

SELECT DATETIME_ADD(DATETIME_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATETIME(), DAY), INTERVAL 14 hour)

```
Gives me 2pm today
```

So, i assumed i could use this in my query

```
Select * from  
TableA  
where CreatedDate Between  
 DATETIME_SUB(DATETIME_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATETIME(), DAY), INTERVAL 10 hour) and DATETIME_ADD(DATETIME_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATETIME(), DAY), INTERVAL 14 hour)
```

However I get the following

> No matching signature for operator BETWEEN for argument types:
>   TIMESTAMP, DATETIME, DATETIME. Supported signature: (ANY) BETWEEN
>   (ANY) AND (ANY)

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `CreatedDate` is `TIMESTAMP` and you need to convert into a `DATETIME`

It could be like:

> where DATETIME(CreatedDate) Between ...

But you could easily write your own statements for TIMESTAMP

> SELECT timestamp_sub(timestamp_trunc(current_timestamp() ,
>   DAY),interval 10 hour)

Comment: ive been staring blankly for half hour and not realised that. Thankyou